# preg_replace return an empty string without error

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

So there's my problem :

```
$var = "93 Avenue d'Aubière";
```

I used this $var with this function:

```
function stripAccents($str) {
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00C0}\x{00C1}\x{00C2}\x{00C3}\x{00C4}\x{00C5}]/u','A', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{0105}\x{0104}\x{00E0}\x{00E1}\x{00E2}\x{00E3}\x{00E4}\x{00E5}]/u','a', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00C7}\x{0106}\x{0108}\x{010A}\x{010C}]/u','C', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00E7}\x{0107}\x{0109}\x{010B}\x{010D}}]/u','c', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{010E}\x{0110}]/u','D', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{010F}\x{0111}]/u','d', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00C8}\x{00C9}\x{00CA}\x{00CB}\x{0112}\x{0114}\x{0116}\x{0118}\x{011A}]/u','E', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00E8}\x{00E9}\x{00EA}\x{00EB}\x{0113}\x{0115}\x{0117}\x{0119}\x{011B}]/u','e', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00CC}\x{00CD}\x{00CE}\x{00CF}\x{0128}\x{012A}\x{012C}\x{012E}\x{0130}]/u','I', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00EC}\x{00ED}\x{00EE}\x{00EF}\x{0129}\x{012B}\x{012D}\x{012F}\x{0131}]/u','i', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{0142}\x{0141}\x{013E}\x{013A}]/u','l', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00F1}\x{0148}]/u','n', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00D2}\x{00D3}\x{00D4}\x{00D5}\x{00D6}\x{00D8}]/u','O', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00F2}\x{00F3}\x{00F4}\x{00F5}\x{00F6}\x{00F8}]/u','o', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{0159}\x{0155}]/u','r', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{015B}\x{015A}\x{0161}]/u','s', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00DF}]/u','ss', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{0165}]/u','t', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00D9}\x{00DA}\x{00DB}\x{00DC}\x{016E}\x{0170}\x{0172}]/u','U', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00F9}\x{00FA}\x{00FB}\x{00FC}\x{016F}\x{0171}\x{0173}]/u','u', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00FD}\x{00FF}]/u','y', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{017C}\x{017A}\x{017B}\x{0179}\x{017E}]/u','z', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00C6}]/u','AE', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{00E6}]/u','ae', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{0152}]/u','OE', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{0153}]/u','oe', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[\x{0022}\x{0025}\x{0026}\x{0027}\x{00A1}\x{00A2}\x{00A3}\x{00A4}\x{00A5}\x{00A6}\x{00A7}\x{00A8}\x{00AA}\x{00AB}\x{00AC}\x{00AD}\x{00AE}\x{00AF}\x{00B0}\x{00B1}\x{00B2}\x{00B3}\x{00B4}\x{00B5}\x{00B6}\x{00B7}\x{00B8}\x{00BA}\x{00BB}\x{00BC}\x{00BD}\x{00BE}\x{00BF}]/u',' ', $str);
        return $str;
    }
```

This return an empty string if I use $var but it return the correct string if I use "93 Avenue d'Aubière" as a parameter.

I tried to use preg_last_error to check if there was any error but it return 0 that means no error.

I'm connectin my DB like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=somedb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
```

Getting data like this :

```
$sqlSelectCommandeExapaq = "SELECT * FROM commande_exapaq WHERE statut = 'en cours'";
$res = $db->query($sqlSelectCommande);
$arrayResCmd = $res->fetchAll();
```

Then I passed $arrayResCmd into this function :

```
public static function generateInterfaceFile($orders_array)
    {
        // Init file
        $record = new DPDStation();
        // Loop through each order
        foreach ($orders_array as $order_data)
        {
            // Add data to file
            $record->add($order_data['customer_adress'], 0, 35);                                                                
        }
        return $record;
    }
```

And there is the DPDStation Constructor :

```
function __construct() {
        $this->line = str_pad("", 1634);
        $this->contenu_fichier = '';
    }
```

And the add function :

```
function add($txt, $position, $length) {
        $txt = $this->stripAccents($txt);
        $this->line = substr_replace($this->line, str_pad($txt, $length), $position, $length);
    }
```

And adding content into the file with :

```
$dpd = new DPDStation();
    $record = $dpd->generateInterfaceFile($arrayResCmd);
    file_put_contents($filename, '$VERSION=110'."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents($filename, $record->contenu_fichier."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Because nothing was add to the file, I look into the stripAccents and the problem seems to come from it.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Works fine for me [can't reproduce it](https://eval.in/390436)

Comment: If it can help, the string that I stock in $var comme from an array which itself come from my DB. I'm using PDO and fetchAll to get this array.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. If it is how you show it here (probably not) your code works. So make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code how you call the function with which string and how you output it

Comment: Your code is probably working. However two notices: 1)`preg_replace` accepts arrays as first and second parameters. 2) did you try `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8'); $str = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $str);`?

Comment: @Rizier123 : I've add some details as you asked

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte : Nope, I'm going to try this now. I tried to delete all the special char and add them one by one. The problem seems to come from the è

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : I tried your solution, it return "93 Avenue d Aubi", pretty close :/

Comment: @Syulwen: see https://eval.in/390513 Take care to work in a full UTF8 environement.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Firstly I used utf8_encode on my string and use your code, it works ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Syulwen: good news, there are many tutorials on the net to fully works in utf8, example: http://j-willette.developpez.com/tutoriels/web/encoder-son-site-en-utf8/setup